# Can I stop a record from being inserted in the object trigger without letting the user know in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-lightning

In order to stay backward compatible with existing customers, I have to be able to handle attachments and files in Salesforce.  Basically, some customers need to be able to insert files and other attachments in our community portal.  I would like to do this without the user knowing which one they are inserting.

The easiest way I can think to do this is to leave the current apex pages used for uploading alone.  Then in the Attachment trigger, I can determine (using a flag somewhere) if the attachment should stay or be changed to a File (ContentVersion).  If it should be a file; then I would create all the necessary records, ContentVersion, ContentDocumentLink and then skip the attachment.  However, I can't figure out a way to stop the attachments from inserting without generating an error to the user.  I really don't want to allow the attachment to insert and then delete it in the after insert trigger because it seems like a lot of overhead.

Using the trigger means I can handle multiple places where community users can add files.  Otherwise, I will have to make changes in all locations to determine which type of record to insert.

So after all of that, the main question is whether or not there is a way to stop inserting records without the addError method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't. You cannot stop the insertion of the `Attachment` record in a trigger without forcing a rollback of the entire transaction or savepoint region, which would include any DML your Attachment trigger performed to add Content objects instead.

The only options that I see are to perform the deletion as you describe, or to change the front-end code to directly insert Content records instead of Attachments.